# alternative to git checkout --orphan when --orphan is not supprted

Tags: git, git-checkout

I have programmed a script that at some point runs

```
git checkout --orphan $BRANCH_NAME
git rm -rf *
git commit --allow-empty -m 'Orphaned Branch inited'
```

Which works exactly as I would like to work

Now I have to deploy it, and don't ask me why, this server's git does not support --orphan option, resulting in

```
error: unknown option `orphan'
```

git checkout --help does not show the option
git --version results in

```
git version 2.9.2
```

And from what I read, --orphan has been around prior to git 2.

Touching the server in any way is not an option, so I need to re write my scripts so I end up with an orphaned, empty branch (and without messing my other branches in the process)

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

edit: updated the commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to get rid of the ref for a new branch:

```
git checkout -b emptybranch
git rm -rf *
git update-ref -d refs/heads/emptybranch
git commit --allow-empty -m 'Orphaned Branch inited'
```

Answer (score 1):

Any Git since 1.7.2 should support `--orphan`; however, `git checkout --orphan` requires a *new* branch name, for a branch that does not yet exist.

If you have an older Git that does not support it (e.g., Git 1.7 on CentOS), you can use `git update-ref` to write the correct (non-existent) new branch name into `HEAD`:

```
git update-ref HEAD refs/heads/new-branch-that-does-not-exist-yet
```

The first commit to such a branch creates it.

Comment: I'm so sorry, my question was wrong. I checked the script and the branch name was being supplied.

Comment: At this point I would check to see if perhaps multiple different versions of Git are installed and you're running the ancient one, or `--orphan` is misspelled (e.g., contains some invisible character such as a zero-width space, or a Unicode character that resembles an ASCII character, but is different).

Comment: It turns out the crippled version of git comes with the oracle linux distribution. Same problem with xmllint, some options are missing :S. Thank you anyways, I manage to resolve the issue :)